# About pandas python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am a beginner to python 3 and I have a question. In pandas, is `read_csv()` a class or a method ?

I suspect `read_csv()` is a class because after you call `data = pd.read_csv()`
, you can subsequently call `data.head()`, an action only possible with a class, because of plenty of methods within this class.

For example:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp_mean = SimpleImputer( strategy='median') 
imp_mean.fit(impute_num)
imputed_num = imp_mean.transform(impute_num)
imputed_num
```

> As shown above, with the SimpleImputer class, first create an object, and then call the methods from that same object. It appears to be just the same as the pd.read_csv() , so I think read_csv() must be a class.

I just checked the documentation for `read_csv()`, which claims it returns a dataframe .But if it is a method, why can it continue to use other methods after `read_csv()`?

from my understanding so far, the method should only return a value and shouldn't continue to use other methods.

Is it necessary to differentiate what type it is when using a new function, method or class? Or should I just think of all of them as an object, because everything in Python is an object.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a class or a method. It's a function. The resulting `DataFrame` is just the return value of `read_csv()`, not an instance of the `read_csv` class or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well my understanding is pd is a class, read_csv() is a method of pd.
And the method returns an instance/object of pd (in your case data)

As data is an instance of a class, it should have all the member methods of the class pd.